# how to compare multiple value in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

i have two tables

in first table for single value 'classroom'  there are multiple (suppose 9)values in 'tag name' and 'tag values' i store these using foreign key in database.

table name **Setting** in this table for single value   there are multiple values
these multiple values are stored in second table(table name **setting_tag**) using foreign key of setting_name

```
    table name "Setting"            table name "Setting_tag"

       setting_name |                 tagname              |    tagvalue      |  setting_name
      ----------------               --------------------------------------------------------
       Classroom    |                 Explanation steps    |    Global        |  classroom
       Lab
       Tutorial                      Content Sequencing        creator defined|  classroom

                                     Real time applications    Necessary      |  classroom

                                     Treatment of topic        Comprehensive  |  classroom

                                     Measurement Instruments   No             |  classroom

                                     Opportunity of errors     No             |  classroom

                                     Number of examples        Low            |  classroom

                                     Variations in assessment  low            |  classroom

                                     Variable manipulation     1              |  classroom
```

similarly in second table(**repository**) there are multiple values for single element,  in 'tag name' and'tag field' but these values(of tag name and tag values) may be **subset of first table**

```
    table name "repository"          table name "repository_tag"

          LO name       |              Tag name         |    Tag values  |   LO name
         -----------------------      ---------------------------------------------

         Convo coding   |             Explanation steps  |    Global       Convo coding

                                      Content Sequencing      both         Convo coding

                                      Real time applications  Necessary    Convo coding

                                      Treatment of topic      Comprehensive  Convo coding

                                      Measurement Instruments No           Convo coding

                                      Opportunity of errors   No           Convo coding

                                      Number of examples      Low          Convo coding

                                     Variations in assessment low          Convo coding

                                      Variable manipulation    1           Convo coding

                                      Bloom’s  Level           Understand  Convo coding
```

**my problem is** how can i compare tag name and tag value of first table to the each element of second table if more then 3 values are matched then **return lo_name from repository table**

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1):

A join of two tables can match tag names and their values:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
ON ( t1.`tagname`, t1.`tagvalue` )
    =
   ( t2.`Tag name`, t2.`Tag values` ) 
;
```

the above query gives matched paiirs of tags+values from both tables.
Assumming that all pairs tag+value in both tables **are unique**, we can count rows returned by this query and compare a result to 3.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 3 <= count(*)
         THEN 'True'
         ELSE 'Not true'
       END as result
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM Table1 t1
  JOIN Table2 t2
  ON ( t1.`tagname`, t1.`tagvalue` )
      =
     ( t2.`Tag name`, t2.`Tag values` ) 
  LIMIT 3
) as subquery;
```

Demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0abf1/7

A `LIMIT 3` clause is not required, hovever it makes the query faster, because it prevents the subquery from joining the whole contents of tables --> We don't want to get the total number of matched pairs (this requires a join of all rows from both tables), we want only to know if at least 3 matched pairs exist - when we find 3 pairs, we can stop looking for more pairs, thus reducing the query total time.

When the pairs in some table are **not unique**, then the query must consider only distinct pairs 
-> a `GROUP BY` or a `DISTINCT` clauses can help in this case:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 3 <= count(*)
         THEN 'True'
         ELSE 'Not true'
       END as result
FROM (
  SELECT t1.`tagname`, t1.`tagvalue`
  FROM Table1 t1
  JOIN Table2 t2
  ON ( t1.`tagname`, t1.`tagvalue` )
      =
     ( t2.`Tag name`, t2.`Tag values` ) 
  GROUP BY t1.`tagname`, t1.`tagvalue`
  LIMIT 3
) as subquery;
```

Demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0abf1/7

Comment: first very thanks for your response, i have updated my question  can you please give some time to suggest solution according to given table structure.